# Geoplot/GeoPandas missalignment in Windows (no Anaconda)

Tags: geopandas, alignment

I am trying to familiarize myself with creating geographic plots in Python using `geopandas` and `geoplot`. So I am working my way through tutorials and documentation.

Currently, I am looking at the [user guide for geoplot](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html), but the created plot and the underlying map are misaligned. I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7 (no Anaconda), and am running inside Jupyter.

Here is the code

```py
%matplotlib inline
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt
import geoplot.crs as gcrs

continental_usa_cities = gpd.read_file(gplt.datasets.get_path('usa_cities'))
continental_usa_cities = continental_usa_cities.query('STATE not in ["AK", "HI", "PR"]')
contiguous_usa = gpd.read_file(gplt.datasets.get_path('contiguous_usa'))

ax = gplt.webmap(contiguous_usa, projection=gcrs.WebMercator())
gplt.pointplot(continental_usa_cities, ax=ax)
```

I am getting two future warnings and an image that is misaligned (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter Notebook showing the missalignment]

What am I doing wrong, and what I can look at to debug/correct the alignment?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Error messages should also be posted as text, since they are legible on all display platforms and can be indexed and found by others with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the updated question. This is for sure a bug, and there is not directly something wrong in your code. And this has already been reported, apparently, here: https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/issues/214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a bug caused by a mismatch between `geoplot` and `contextily` (the package that `geoplot` uses for adding the web map background), see https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/issues/214. That will certainly be fixed in a future version of `geoplot`, but for now, you can use `contextily` directly, by changing this line of your code:

```
ax = gplt.webmap(contiguous_usa, projection=gcrs.WebMercator())
```

to

```
import contextily 
contextily.add_basemap(ax, source=contextily.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
```

Full working example:

```
ax = gplt.pointplot(continental_usa_cities, projection=gcrs.WebMercator())

import contextily
contextily.add_basemap(ax, source=contextily.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
```

[image]